# How to debug the reason why this transaction reverts?

Tags: solidity

I'm having a hard time debugging my transaction.

This is what I've done:

- I have deployed [an ERC721 contract from OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721#constructing_an_erc721_token_contract) to Ropsten
- I have verified source code (see [deployed contract here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa139add45b8c3ddf43638839b619252078b116fb))
- I have run the transaction correctly in Remix (e.g. `createItem` method)

So I know `createItem` function works correctly as I can run it from Remix, but when I try to send the same transaction from my app, it reverts and I don't know why.

**Here's an example of a reverted transaction:**

- [TX 0x13058bc9](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x13058bc9f85d2589681eb01d62ef2e63d73533caa14001aefae397dbcc2fa7fa)

I debug the input data [with this tool](https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/) and it seems to be OK ‍♂️ - two params are sent: `address` and `string`

```json
{
  "method": "createItem",
  "types": [
    "address",
    "string"
  ],
  "inputs": [
    "ee27673e55f7bed7ccd8828756c73707cf77b1cf",
    "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmPTh9RjkugfgJ5jY7Vac617o63J6q7etHW2nnjKEsreJS"
  ],
  "names": [
    "website",
    "tokenURI"
  ]
}
```

I have used Tenderly.io to try to debug the revert but there is no further explanations about the cause (see screenshot below):

[image]

Anyone knows how I can debug the reason why my transaction reverts?

Comment: what is the code you are using to send the transaction from your app?

Comment: The input data is wrong. It starts with `0x32366662373663323030303030`, it should start like `0x26fb76c20000000000`. It seems you are missing `0x` in some part of your encoding.

Comment: correct! Thank you very much @Ismael my encoded data was not prefixed with `0x` indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ismael spotted in replies, my encoded data was actually simply missing `0x` prefix.